# Spring-Boot REST endpoint, increase number of retries/connection from a single host Tomcat will accepts

Tags: python, spring-boot, rest, tomcat

I'm load testing a Spring Boot API, a POC to show the team it will handle high throughput. I'm making the requests with a Python script that uses a multiprocessing pool. When I start sending more than like 10,000 records I get an error that "Max retries exceeded" which I've determined means the endpoint is refusing the connection from the client, because it's making too many connections.

Is there a Tomcat setting to allow more requests from a client (temporarily) for something like load testing? I tried setting "server.tomcat.max-threads" in the applicatin.properties file, but that doesn't seem to help.